# Change multiple values in column in a tidyverse fashion

Tags: r, list, dplyr, dataset

For illustration lets use the built in mpg data.

```
> mpg %>% select(model) %>% unique()
#   model             
#   <chr>             
# 1 a4                
# 2 a4 quattro        
# 3 a6 quattro  
# ...
```

I want to change all values with "a4 quattro" into "a4" and "a6 quattro" into "a6". I know about gsub

```
> mpg <- mpg %>% mutate(model = gsub("a4 quattro", "a4", model))
> mpg <- mpg %>% mutate(model = gsub("a6 quattro", "a6", model))
```

But is there a way for me to do this in one line?

Furthermore, is there a way to generalize this further? Say I got a nested list type object with structure

```
> a
# $a4
# [1] "a4 quattro" "a4 model 2" "model 3"   
#
# $a6
# [1] "a6 quattro" "model k"
```

Is there an easy way to change all instances of the elements in a$a4 that exists in mpg (our data) into the name of the sub list "a4" and the same for a$a6 (and potentially more list elements in a)?
Alternatively is there a "better" data structure to use for this?

I want this to be done in a "tidyverse" fashion. Purrr functionality is ok, but not for loops.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at tidyfast::dt_case_when(). This function has the same syntax as dplyr::case_when() but is build on the very fast data.table::fifelse().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `recode` to do an exact match and replace one value with another.

```
library(tidyverse)
mpg %>% 
   mutate(model = recode(model, 'a4 quattro' = 'a4', 'a6 quattro' = 'a6'))
```

Maybe if you have some pattern like here you could use some regex to achieve desired output.

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(model = sub(' quattro', '', model))
```

For limited values you can use `case_when` :

```
mpg %>%
  mutate(model = case_when(model %in% c("a4 quattro", "a4 model 2", "model 3") ~ 'a4', 
                           model %in% c("a6 quattro", "model k") ~'a6', 
                           TRUE ~ model))
```

A more general solution if you have a list already you could convert it into dataframe and join with the original data.

```
a <- list(a4 = c("a4 quattro", "a4 model 2", "model 3"), 
          a6 = c("a6 quattro", "model k"))

enframe(a) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  inner_join(mpg, by = c('value' = 'model'))
```